# Windows XP or ME

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems

I have just been given an amazing as new embroidery machine, top of the line. It's software will only run with Windows XP or ME, there are no updates on it as I have already contacted the company. I am currently running 8.1, will not go to windows 10! Can I run XP on an external drive to use the software or do I need to find an old laptop with it on?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the interface of the machine to the computer, you may be able to use a virtual machine on your existing computer. Within the virtual machine Windows XP is going to be substantially more stable than Windows ME and relatively easy to install. Using a virtual machine also provides a bit of protection from the end-of-life status which XP currently "enjoys."

Virtual machines will connect to external ports such as USB and network, if you require such a connection to the machine. My sister's machine uses USB flash drives as the means to transfer files from the computer to the device, which would be supported in a virtual machine environment.

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is one such program available, at no charge, which makes it all the more attractive to budget users. There are others that can be identified via a search for "virtual machine software" with the added term "free" if needed.